# Server daemon with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, daemon

I am rather new to Spring and I still dont know my way around this framework.

Now, I need to create a service, that runs a P2P (TomP2P) installation. Hence, once started, the service must not halt while idle, but instead continue to run the TomP2P node. i.e.: a daemon service, preferably started via /etc/init.d/*

I googled for tutorials, but couldn't find any. How do I do this?

Comment: Have a look at Spring Boot. With the new released 1.3.0, it supports executable JARs, which can linked as services in Linux.

Comment: Does Spring have to register the application as a daemon or would something like a Java service wrapper do the trick as well?